# Regex that matches [number-n]-WORD but not [number]-WORD

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I want to create a shell script, that iterates through folders and deletes folders that match [versionnumber-n] where n > 0

the version number is in a file that's content is like:

```
MAVEN_VERSION=1.2.7.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Here's an example:

The file listing is like

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul 29 10:54 ./
drwxrwxr-x 20 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul  4 09:20 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul 23 12:35 1.2.6.0-SNAPSHOT/
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul 28 23:13 1.2.7.0-SNAPSHOT/
-rw-rw-r--  1 jenkins jenkins  403 Jul 29 10:11 maven-metadata-local.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  403 Jul 28 23:13 maven-metadata-mtx-snapshots.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   40 Jul 28 23:13 maven-metadata-mtx-snapshots.xml.sha1
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  403 Jul 28 23:13 maven-metadata.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   32 Jul 28 23:13 maven-metadata.xml.md5
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   40 Jul 28 23:13 maven-metadata.xml.sha1
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  186 Jul 28 23:13 resolver-status.properties
```

Where I want the script to delete the folder 1.2.6.0-SNAPSHOT/ but not 1.2.7.0-SNAPSHOT/. If there where folders like 1.2.5.0-SNAPSHOT/ 1.2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/ them too.

What I have at this point:

```
.*(?!1.2.7.0)(-SNAPSHOT)
```

Which unfortunately matches both folders (in the example above)

edit: just hit submit too early ...

Comment: Please show an example list of those folders. And show how you list them.

Comment: I just hit submit accidentally ... apologies

Comment: So you want to delete everything BUT 1.2.7.0 version?

Answer (score 1):

With Bash you can just use negation with extended pathname expansion.

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -fr /dir/1.2.!(7).0-SNAPSHOT
```

Dry run example:

```
$ ls -1
1.2.10.0-SNAPSHOT
1.2.5.0-SNAPSHOT
1.2.6.0-SNAPSHOT
1.2.7.0-SNAPSHOT
a
$ echo rm -fr 1.2.!(7).0-SNAPSHOT
rm -fr 1.2.10.0-SNAPSHOT 1.2.5.0-SNAPSHOT 1.2.6.0-SNAPSHOT
```

See [Extended Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) and [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Thing is, the number changes over time. I have it written in a file, from which I want to read it and delete all folders smaller than that number. This should go in a script, that runs regularly.

Comment: @MichaelNiemand You can use version sort and sed to show all but latest version: `ls -1 | sort -V | sed '$d'`

Comment: Of course `find` would apply to that as well, not just `ls` but you get the concept. If you need help to sanely delete those files despite spaces on filenames comment back your solution based from it and I'd give a suggestion.

Comment: This finds all the folders I want: 
`find -type d -regex '.*SNAPSHOT' | sort -V | sed '$d'`

How do I them then? sorry, I'm quite a shell noob :)

Comment: Well for me the safest is to use `xargs`: `find -type d -regex '.*SNAPSHOT' | sort -V | sed '$d' | xargs -d '\n' rm -fr`

Comment: Thanks. This works, if I have only one folder though. I have about a dozen folders, everyone having subfolders with `1.2.6.0-SNAPSHOT
1.2.7.0-SNAPSHOT`.
Isn't there a way to say like "take all folders named "...-SNAPSHOT" but not "[value from file]"?

Comment: You can try `find -type d -regex '.*SNAPSHOT' -not -name '1.2.7.0-SNAPSHOT'`.

Answer (score 0):

How I did it in the end:

```
if [ -z "$MAVEN_VERSION_SERVER" ]
then
echo "\$MAVEN_VERSION_SERVER NOT set! \n exiting ..."
else
find /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/de/db/mtxbes -mindepth  1 -type d -regex '.*SNAPSHOT' -not -name $MAVEN_VERSION_SERVER | xargs -d '\n' rm -fr
fi
```

(the $MAVEN_VERSION_SERVER gets set and read with groovy scripts before)